# iOS - Custom view frame.size.height gives a 0 value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS programming. I was following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) tutorial, but I have a problem with the intrinsicContentSize() function. I wrote this code:

```
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
        let width = (buttonSize * starCount) + (spacing * (starCount - 1))
        return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)
    }
```

It belongs to a custom class that I created to make a custom view (it's a control that must handle a five-star rating).
The problem is that frame.size.height gives a 0 value, so the view is not displayed on the screen.
So, where is the problem? I have copied the code from the tutorial, you can check it if you go under "Implement a custom control" and then to "Declare a Constant for the Button Size".
I'm using Xcode beta, so swift version is 3.0, while the tutorial is for swift 2.3, could this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. intrinsicContentSize() has been changed to a property so you'd override it like this:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let buttonSize = Int(frame.height)
    let width = (buttonSize * starCount) + (spacing * (starCount - 1))
    return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)
}
```

Comment: That;s the proper way to override but it results in a big red box at the bottom of the screen instead of the 5 buttons for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [StackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) in your project? Check the image bellow:

[image: stack view]

Comment: Yes, I did. I have also added constraints. I have just found out that if I delete the top layout guide constrain, the view is displayed as I wanted. But I don't understand why is this happening...